# When i press Delete button The Selected Record of Datagridview in Vb.net not physically deleted from my access table

Tags: vb.net

i am using Datagridview in vb.net connects data source with ODBC DSN connection.
When record are Load in Data Grid View and i select a row and press delete button . the selected row will be deleted from grid view but not physically deleted from my access table.
I read some related problem but i cant understand. Please Help

Comment: That's correct. The `DataGridView` doesn't know anything about your data-source (as it could be filled with data from a local text-file, a read-only data service, a web request, etc... so it just can't automatically issue commands back to it to tell it to delete data. You need to handle that yourself.

Comment: Data filled from Access Database.

Comment: You have asked 8 questions and not accepted a single answer. The one I checked had 2 excellent answers. Show the code in your delete button. Does the code attempt to interact with the database?

Comment: Sorry , i have no idea of Accept Answer before your comments so i mark my accepted answer. and Now after complete studding the ADO.net  i think i am fool for asking  this question. i assume that when i select the row in data grid and Press the delete button then the record automatically deleted from the table linked with this data grid . Now i attached some code behind key press event and i got some idea. Thanks